# How to give a ML model an information that a store is closed or open?

Tags: machine-learning

When predicting sales, how can you make ML models predict 0 sales when the shop is closed?

I tried to use a dummy variable with 2 columns one for open and the other one for close but it's not efficient.
I don't understand why my models can't figure out that when there is a 1 in a column they should always predict 0.

**edit :**

Indeed, to predict 0 sales with a model of ML, just simply remove the days without sales or if the variable store_open = 0 do not use the prediction algorithm and simply predict 0.

However, the reason I asked this question is to use my dummy variable with time series. I wanted to check if an ML model was able to predict 0 for a closed day and therefore understand in a time series that some days are at 0 because the shop is closed and others are at 0 because there were no sales. That's why I try to predict sales when a shop is closed.

This being said, in the case of a model using time series as an RNN, how can I integrate the closed and open day in my data?

Comment: Which model? The function sales = f(predictors) they fit might not be flexible enough to allow that if is_closed=1, then sales should always be 0, whatever the values of the other predictors. An additive model for instance can't do this. A decision tree can but since the're fit in a greedy way it might be missed nontheless.

Comment: Why waste your energy modeling that? You know the answer. If a store is closed, you predict zero sales. If you need some kind of software system to make predictions, write some kind of if/else screening code: if store closed, predict zero sales; else, apply your model to the data.

Comment: @CloseToC I tried this with Random forest and RNN, and yes it works better with a decision tree but it's not perfect

Comment: @Dave And I want to add this feature for multiple reasons. I know that when a shop is closed it's always 0 but I will use times series with RNN or LSTM.  I think this feature is important so that the model knows that sometimes it's 0 sales because stores are closed and sometimes it's 0 sales simply because no product has been sold.

Comment: @Dave Also, I will add a feature for public holidays. And sometimes shops are closed during public holidays but sometimes thay are open and as I am working with different shops I think I need a dummy variable for open/closed days.

Comment: As a practical matter, you can fit your model excluding days on which the store is closed, since if the store is closed, those other predictions are irrelevant any way. This should also improve the model's ability to predict sales on open days

Comment: @CloseToC yes indeed like Dave said "Why waste your energy modeling that? You know the answer. If a store is closed, you predict zero sales.", but this might not be a good solution for time series

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a line of research dealing with a similar problem: *rules-first classification*.

It may be considered an open topic of research (without much activity), but a nice [paper on the topic](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v89/cohen19a.html) was recently published in PMLR.

Short summary: The authors propose a classification problem where the output label can be perfectly predicted by a binary rule (like the `store_open` variable you describe) and otherwise predicted with some error by a linear classifier. They go on to study the properties of this problem and limitations of algorithms designed to solve it.

On a more practical note, you may consider filtering your feature vectors based on the `store_open` variable by short-circuiting your outputs to be 0 when `store_open==true`, and running an alternative algorithm when `store_open==false`.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at it thank you ! 
I added an edit, this solution work for model with "simple" input, but the reason behind my question concerns the use of this dummy  variable with time series.  
My question may not have been explicit, so I re-explained my objective in the edit.